# AngularJS counter

Tags: angularjs, counter, badge

I need help understanding why my counter doesn't work.

I need a badge to increment/decrement every time I click. When the increment/decrement is done and i pass that counter to my scope badge, i get undefined. But if i add a static number it works.

```
 app.factory('badgeCounter', function ($log) {

  var items=0;
  var num;

  return {
    countItems: function () {
      ++items;
      $log.info('items: ' + items);
      return items;
    },
    removeItems: function () {
      items--;
      $log.info('items: ' + items);
    },
    listItems: function (items) {
      $log.info('total de items:=> ' + items);
      //return alert(items);
      return items;
    },
    cleanItems: function () {
      return items = 0;
    }
  }
```

Every time i make an increment, I call the function to see if the increment worked.

```
badgeCounter.countItems();
badgeCounter.listItems();
```

It works. But if set it to scope, I don't get the total increment. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong and help me?

```
$scope.items = badgeCounter.listItems();

<div ng-controller = "basketProductController">    
  <span> 
     <button  ng-click="openBasket()" ng-init="items" class="button button-icon ion-ios-cart-outline">
      <span class="badge badge-assertive header-badge"></span>
     </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `items` argument in the `listItems` function signature.

Change

`listItems: function (items) {`

to

`listItems: function () {`

**Explanation**

Having the `items` argument in the method signature would mean that within the `listItems` function, the variable name `items` will refer to the argument passed in (which is `undefined` since you are not passing in anything) and not the `items` variable in your `badgeCounter` service which is the counter you are looking to return.